# Filter H2OFrame on pandas dates and time (python)

Tags: python, h2o

Just getting started on h2o.ai, I'm loving the algos and distributed computing but stuck on data manipulation...

How would I be able to filter a H2OFrame on `Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:00:00')` AND `numpy.datetime64('2011-01-02T00:00:00.000000000')`?

So for example I'd like to do the equivalent of this pandas date slicing

```
import pandas as pd
import h2o
h2o.init()

dft=pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=10), 'value': range(10)})
dft.ix[dft['date']>dft['date'].min()]
dft.ix[dft['date']>dft['date'].values[1]]
```

I've failed at this

```
dfh2o=h2o.H2OFrame(dft)
dfh2o[dfh2o['date']>dft['date'].min()] # causes error
dfh2o[dfh2o['date']>dft['date'].values[1]] # causes error
dfh2o['date2']=dfh2o['date'].asdate() # this function doesn't exist
```

NOTE that I'd like to filter on the original date values because I get them from elsewhere and it will be difficult to include them in the H2OFrame. That is I don't just want something like this

```
dfh2o[dfh2o['date']>dfh2o['date'].min()]
dfh2o[dfh2o['date']>dfh2o[1,'date']]
```

And I'm not sure how the Timestamp gets converted by H2OFrame

```
dft['date'].astype('int64').min()
Out[16]: 1293840000000000000

dfh2o['date'].min()
Out[17]: 1293858000000.0
```

Comment: when you convert a pandas dataframe to an h2oframe all elements from the timestamp column get converted to millis since the epoch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have reported as a bug in H2O as described:
https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3895

Also described here: 
https://community.h2o.ai/questions/1410/filter-h2oframe-on-pandas-dates-and-time-python.html